# Giga base or Giga byte

Tags: bioinformatics, genomes

> "we reported ~2.66- Gb genome sequence of"
>
> "we generated 191.5 Gb high quality reads"

I am very confused with these two quoted lines and I am not sure about giga byte or giga base pair.

and an additional question: How to count base pairs from a FASTQ file?
I have read numbers and length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This refers to base pairs.

File size has no particular meaning beyond practical considerations, given that it depends on the format. (For example, 2bit files use 2 bits per base, as the name indicates, compared to the 8 bits necessary for each letter in a plain text format like FASTA & derivatives.)

For your additional question, (number of reads * length of each read) gives the total length of sequence contained in the file. It is not really a property of the file format, but a parameter of the sequencing run.